Deriving the Heisenberg equation of motion in Jonathan Oppenheim's classical gravity paper
I have been reading through A postquantum theory of classical gravity? by Jonathan Oppenheim and am struggle to derive the Heisenberg Equation of motion (eq 3 in the paper) for the toy example he sets up to illustrate the problems that may still exist even for a quantum theory of gravity.

Take for example the interaction
Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_{MG} = \hat{H}_M ⊗ \hat{H}_G$, and the limit where the M
and G system are close to a product state with density
matrix $\hat{ρ}_{MG} ≈ \hat{σ}_M ⊗ \hat{σ}_G$. Then, for as long as the two
systems remain approximately uncorrelated, Heisenberg’s
equation of motion for the M system, after tracing out the G
system gives $$\frac{\partial\hat{σ}_M}{\partial t} \approx -i [\hat{σ}_M, \hat{H}_M] \otimes \langle \hat{H}_G \rangle$$

My main issue here is the negative sign/order of commutator. When trying to derive this myself using the Von-Neumann equation I get:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\frac{\partial\rho_{MG}}{\partial t} &= -i[\hat H_M \otimes \hat{H}_G, \hat{\sigma}_M \otimes \hat{\sigma}_G]\\
&=-i([\hat{H}_M, \hat{σ}_M] \otimes \hat{H}_G\hat{\sigma}_G + \hat{\sigma}_M\hat{H}_M \otimes [\hat{H}_G, \hat{σ}_G])
\end{alignat*}
Taking the trace over G, $Tr_G$, of both sides I get that the second term on RHS vanishes since $Tr_G([\hat{H}_G, \hat{σ}_G]) = 0$ leaving us with
$$\frac{\partial\sigma_M}{\partial t} = -i [\hat{H}_M, \hat{σ}_M] \cdot \langle\hat{H}_G\rangle.$$
This has the opposite sign as the result in the text and I'm not quite sure where my mistake was. I am using the Schrodinger picture in my derivation but even in the Heisenberg picture applying the equation of motion to a density operator we would get
$$i\frac{\partial\rho_H}{\partial t} = [\hat{\rho}_H, \hat{H}_H] + i(\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t})_H = 0$$ since the density operator is stationary in the Heisenberg picture. Simplifying this gives
$$(\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t})_H = -i [\hat{H}_H, \hat{\rho}_H]$$ which is consistent with the Von-Neumann equation I used in my derivation.

This seems like a typo in the paper, doesn't it?

That's my suspicion, but as its been a while since I've done proper QM derivations I wanted to get some feedback on if I had made a mistake somewhere. Also thought it would have been caught in peer review.
